# Web interface for SFTP server

Tags: sftp

An SFTP client such as CuteFTP or Filezilla provides a rick user interface for an SFTP server. These are clients that are installed locally on the user's PC. Instead of a client installed at the user's side, is it possible to set up a web-based user interface on the SFTP server, so that a user with only a browser is able to access the files on the server? Are such open source or commerical products available that can be deployed on the SFTP server for enhancing the file transfer experience?
Note: The base server needs to be SFTP as there will be scripts that clients will be using to transfer files in a non-interactive manner. For interactive usage, I am looking for a web interface that be serve as an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out: https://filebrowser.org/features

There is another good one called "droppy" but its no longer active and apparently has too many git forks at the moment to know where it will go.

The question you need to answer is the application value/scope.

You can always go with Dropbox or something too depending on the user's intended application.

Comment: Note: The base server needs to be SFTP as there will be scripts that clients will be using to transfer files in a non-interactive manner. For interactive usage, I am looking for a web interface that be serve as an add-on. Filebrowser seems to be a server in its own right.